# Angular custom filter is not displayed

Tags: angularjs

I've been dealing with this for the last day trying to figure out what I've been doing wrong.  I'm trying to pass a value into a filter and return a string from a hash that's been built from a return from a factory.  I can get it to work in a similar function that doesn't call the factory, but whenever I return from the factory I'm unable to display the string, even though the appropriate string is show in the console. Am I missing something really easy here?

Controller here:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.stuff = 1;
}])
```

Factory here:

```
app.factory('factory', ['$q', function($q) {
  var list = [
    {set1: 1,set2: 'name1'}, 
    {set1: 2,set2: 'name2'}
    ];
  var list2 = [
    {set1: 1,set2: 'name6'},
    {set1: 2,set2: 'name7'}
    ]
  var service = {
    getList: getList
  }
  return service;

  function getList(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (id === 1) {
      deferred.resolve(list);
    } else if (id === 2) {
      deferred.resolve(list2);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}])
```

Filter here:

```
app.filter('customFilter', ['factory', function(factory) {
  var factoryHash = {};
  return function(input, id) {
    factory.getList(id)
      .then(function(res) {
        angular.forEach(res, function(value) {
          this[value.set1] = value.set2;
        }, factoryHash);
        console.log('factoryHash', factoryHash[input])
        return factoryHash[input];
      })
  }
}])
```

plnkr is here.

https://plnkr.co/edit/c4hYrRrdbBF9M2o5tVV5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a promise inside a filter because the filter will be executed any way and when your promise ends the function already return a result to the UI.